# SpringBoot + Angular 5 - Do we need a server-side controller?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm currently reading [this tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot) about using Angular 5 to migrate my application from Thymeleaf to Angular 5 using REST.

To edit entities, it calls directly its repository from Angular's controller.

But, I'm afraid to do so. Is it a good practice?
Currently, I use a server-side controller, which makes controls before calling server-side services. These services call repository.

Am I good doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the whole point but here it goes:

I would go with the RestController -> Service -> Repository approach (actually we use it a lot in our company). It not seems to be a right or wrong choice but more a context decision.

If it's a simple application that has simple CRUD logic, it seems to be more productive to have less layers in you server-side code, but even simple application tend to have more validation and business logic than simple CRUD calls.

You could also have RestController -> Repository mixed with RestController -> Service -> Repository approach when there's no reason to have a Service layer.

In Angular, you can also use the concept of the components calling services that than calls your rest controllers on the server side. This is a nice default architecture that works fine for many projects.

Hope it could be of some help :)